# sbrk(0) and sbrk(size) both return the same address

Tags: c

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void *my_malloc(size_t size){
 void *p;
 void *q;
 p = sbrk(0);
 /* If sbrk fails, we return NULL */
 q = sbrk(size);
 if(q == (void *)-1){
  return NULL;
 }
 printf("\n size : %d  p : 0x%x q : 0x%x \n",size,p,q);
 return p;
}
int main(){
 int *p;
 p = my_malloc(5);
 printf("\n p : 0x%x \n",p);
}
```

brk(2) place the break at the given adress addr and return 0 if successful, -1 otherwise. The global errno symbol indicate the nature of the error.
sbrk(2) move the break by the given increment (in bytes.) Depending on system implementation, it returns the previous or the new break adress. On failure, it returns (void *)-1 and set errno. On some system sbrk accepts negative values (in order to free some mapped memory.)
Since sbrk’s specification does not fix the meaning of its result, we won’t use the returned value when moving the break. But, we can use a special case of sbrk: when increment is nul (i.e. sbrk(0)), the returned value is the actual break adress (the previous and the new break adresses are the same.) sbrk is thus used to retrieve the begining of the heap which is the initial position of the break.
So using sbrk as main tool to implement malloc.

sbrk(0) as well as sbrk(size) both return the same address, what i was expecting is that the sbrk(size) should return the address of 5 bytes ahead from the sbrk(0).

Comment: What is your actual question ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you use `sbrk(0)` you get the *current* "break" address.

When you use `sbrk(size)` you get the *previous* "break" address, i.e. the one before the change.

So if you call it once with a size of zero followed by a call with a positive size, then both will return the same value. If you call it again with a zero size *after* the call with positive size, it will return the *new* address.

Comment: Hi,
can you please explain what is the break address?

Comment: @user1079065 I recommend you read the [Wikipedia article on `sbrk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk), it explains it pretty well.

Comment: I read the same in the man page, but the wording had me confused a little: _"On success, sbrk() returns the previous program break.  (If the break  was increased,  then  this  value is a pointer to the start of the newly allocated memory)."_ The start of the newly allocated memory is the same as the previous break address.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I think there's a mistake in the wikipedia article. "Upon successful completion, the brk subroutine returns a value of 0, and the sbrk subroutine returns the prior value of the program break (if the available space is increased the return value points to the start of the new area). If either subroutine is unsuccessful, a value of −1 is returned and the errno global variable is set to indicate the error." How can `sbrk` return the prior value and the start of the new area. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SujayPhadke That "if" changes the meaning of the return value. `sbrk` returns *either* one thing, *or* another thing.

Comment: The second if, yes. In case of a success, there's no need of that if - sbrk() always returns the previous break in case of success. isn't that right?